# Microsoft Graph delta: recurring calendar events returning incorrect start/end

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an app that loads calendar items into a database, and needs to stay in sync with the given user's calendar. Unfortunately, when querying Microsoft Graph for a given date range using Delta tokens, the original event's data is being returned. However, if the Delta call is removed from the query, recurring events are returned as expected.

The call without Delta:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2018-06-26T00:00:00&endDateTime=2018-06-27T00:00:00&$select=id,subject,start,end
```

Returns:

> ```
>     {
>         "@odata.etag": "W/\"vDPrV1TQYUmam8nxPycXGwABJbtmSQ==\"",
>         "id": "AAMkADZhMjA2YTNmLTM0NDktNDYyNy05Njk2LTRjNThhMDZkZDBmOQFRAAgI1dr3wqKAAEYAAAAAY_l4isQ6OkOWdkEvK3rrDQcAvDPrV1TQYUmam8nxPycXGwAAAAABDQAAvDPrV1TQYUmam8nxPycXGwAAAtcOVAAAEA==",
>         "subject": "Daily recurring event",
>         "start": {
>             "dateTime": "2018-06-26T14:30:00.0000000",
>             "timeZone": "UTC"
>         },
>         "end": {
>             "dateTime": "2018-06-26T14:45:00.0000000",
>             "timeZone": "UTC"
>         }
>     }
> ```

However, when trying to add the "delta" call to the request using the same start/end dates, the event's ORIGINAL dates (and Id) are returned. Additionally, the SELECT columns are ignored, entirely.

The call with Delta:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView/delta?startDateTime=2018-06-26T00:00:00&endDateTime=2018-06-27T00:00:00&$select=id,subject,start,end
```

Returns:

> ```
>     {
>         "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.event",
>         "@odata.etag": "W/\"vDPrV1TQYUmam8nxPycXGwABJbtmSQ==\"",
>         "createdDateTime": "2017-04-19T15:02:38.8680605Z",
>         "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-06-25T14:15:14.2194888Z",
>         "changeKey": "vDPrV1TQYUmam8nxPycXGwABJbtmSQ==",
>         "categories": [],
>         "originalStartTimeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
>         "originalEndTimeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
>         "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000050B9E76D2CF2D001000000000000000010000000831C6E0657580F44A0799E55EB5F2E49",
>         "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
>         "isReminderOn": true,
>         "hasAttachments": false,
>         "subject": "Daily recurring event",
>         "bodyPreview": "",
>         "importance": "normal",
>         "sensitivity": "normal",
>         "isAllDay": false,
>         "isCancelled": false,
>         "isOrganizer": false,
>         "responseRequested": true,
>         "seriesMasterId": null,
>         "showAs": "busy",
>         "type": "seriesMaster",
>         ...
>         "id": "AAMkADZhMjA2YTNmLTM0NDktNDYyNy05Njk2LTRjNThhMDZkZDBmOQBGAAAAAABj6XiKxDo6Q5Z2QS8reusNBwC8M_tXVNBhSZqbyfE-JxcbAAAAAAENAAC8M_tXVNBhSZqbyfE-JxcbAAAC1w5UAAA=",
>         "responseStatus": {
>             "response": "accepted",
>             "time": "2017-04-19T15:02:00Z"
>         },
>         "body": {
>             "contentType": "html",
>             "content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\">\r\n<!-- converted from rtf -->\r\n<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<font face=\"Calibri\" size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt;\">\r\n<div>&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div>&nbsp;</div>\r\n</span></font>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
>         },
>         "start": {
>             "dateTime": "2015-09-22T14:30:00.0000000",
>             "timeZone": "UTC"
>         },
>         "end": {
>             "dateTime": "2015-09-22T14:45:00.0000000",
>             "timeZone": "UTC"
>         },
>         "location": {
>             "displayName": "on your feet",
>             "locationType": "default",
>             "uniqueId": "on your feet",
>             "uniqueIdType": "private"
>         },
>         "locations": [
>             {
>                 "displayName": "on your feet",
>                 "locationType": "default",
>                 "uniqueId": "on your feet",
>                 "uniqueIdType": "private"
>             }
>         ],
>         "recurrence": {
>             "pattern": {
>                 "type": "weekly",
>                 "interval": 1,
>                 "month": 0,
>                 "dayOfMonth": 0,
>                 "daysOfWeek": [
>                     "monday",
>                     "tuesday",
>                     "wednesday",
>                     "thursday",
>                     "friday"
>                 ],
>                 "firstDayOfWeek": "sunday",
>                 "index": "first"
>             },
>             "range": {
>                 "type": "noEnd",
>                 "startDate": "2015-09-22",
>                 "endDate": "0001-01-01",
>                 "recurrenceTimeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
>                 "numberOfOccurrences": 0
>             }
>         },
>         "attendees": [
>             {
>                 "type": "required",
>                 "status": {
>                     "response": "none",
>                     "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
>                 },
>                 "emailAddress": {
>                     "name": "Nunya Biz",
>                     "address": "biz@markie.com"
>                 }
>             }
>         ],
>         "organizer": {
>             "emailAddress": {
>                 "name": "Nunya Biz",
>                 "address": "biz@markie.com"
>             }
>         }
>     },
> ```

Can anyone tell me how can I get the Delta query to return the recurring event's instance, as opposed to the "seriesMaster"?

Comment: Select is not supported for delta querys (see [doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_events)). Normaly delta querys should return the occurences and exceptions of recurring events. I tested it and it still seems to work like that. Maybe there is no occurence in the intervall you specified (startDateTime=2018-06-26T00:00:00&endDateTime=2018-06-27T00:00:00). It is just one day and your seriesMaster contains the the recurrence pattern type "weekly".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @MichaelHufnagel. The recurrence pattern is weekly, but includes every weekday (Mon - Fri), therefore it shows up daily.  The big concern is that the start dateTime being returned is "2015-09-22T14:30:00.0000000", which is most definitely not within the range.

Comment: To further clarify, the result (above) is the data returned by the request, so it definitely "finds" a recurring event, which it returns. The main issue is that it seems to be returning the original event, not the actual unfurled recurring event. When removing the delta call, you can see that it returns the event properly, with a start/end dateTime within the range, and a different Id.

Also, thanks for the input on the "select" not being supported; that was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out! The delta returns the seriesMaster, but also returns the instance details (occurrence) at the end. My bad for leaving it out of the results in the original post.

The missing link:

```
    {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.event",
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"DwAAABYAAAC8M+tXVNBhSZqbyfE/JxcbAAElu2ZJ\"",
        "seriesMasterId": "AAMkADZhMjA2YTNmLTM0NDktNDYyNy05Njk2LTRjNThhMDZkZDBmOQBGAAAAAABj6XiKxDo6Q5Z2QS8reusNBwC8M_tXVNBhSZqbyfE-JxcbAAAAAAENAAC8M_tXVNBhSZqbyfE-JxcbAAAC1w5UAAA=",
        "type": "occurrence",
        "id": "AAMkADZhMjA2YTNmLTM0NDktNDYyNy05Njk2LTRjNThhMDZkZDBmOQFRAAgI1dr3wqKAAEYAAAAAY_l4isQ6OkOWdkEvK3rrDQcAvDPrV1TQYUmam8nxPycXGwAAAAABDQAAvDPrV1TQYUmam8nxPycXGwAAAtcOVAAAEA==",
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2018-06-26T14:30:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2018-06-26T14:45:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    },
```

Note that the "type" = "occurrence", and the "seriesMasterId" points back to the seriesMaster's Id field. This contains the correct start/end information for the event.

Comment: Is it lists the deleted occurence?

Comment: Hi, I honestly don't remember, but I believe it was pretty clear/easy to figure out which ones were deleted.

Comment: When i delete an event occurence,it just gets removed from occurences listed by the delta query.Not able to identify the deleted occurence.

Comment: Very interesting. I thought it listed deletions at the very bottom. I wish I still had this code-base to work on (I'm no longer with that company) so I could check. If you want, you can post up the full response, and I'll see if I can see anything, but it has been a little while.

Comment: Not able to post my response since its too long.Occurences are being displayed except on the deleted day occurence.